# Excel VBA: CSV file wont show data?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I've been writing a code which works 90% of the way. My job is to spind specific numbers in a row, change these numbers to another number, and at the same time the code has to create a CSV file with the new numbers, which it does. However the CSV file is empty when i look in it? The data do not appear in the CSV file, could someone point out where my code is wrong? I have certain data from rows that has to appear in the new CSV document with the newly created numbers
This is my code:

```
    Sub Assignment8()

ranrow = Worksheets("Base").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    file = FreeFile

    Open Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Assignment8.csv" For Output Lock Write As #FreeFile

    For currow = 2 To ranrow

    If (Left(Worksheets("Base").Range("L" & currow).Value, 6) = "262015") Then

        nstudent = "18"

        randomNumber = Int((99999 - 10000) * Rnd()) + 10000

        nstudent = nstudent & randomNumber

        nstudent = nstudent & Worksheets("Base").Range("I" & currow).Value

        currentstudentID = Worksheets("Base").Range("L" & currow).Value
        currentEnrollPeriod = Worksheets("Base").Range("E" & currow).Value

        Print #fileID, newstudentID & ";" & currentstudentID & ";" & currentEnrollPeriod

        Worksheets("Base").Range("L" & currow).Value = newstudentID

    End If

Next

Close #FreeFile

End Sub
```

Moreover i have to make the code in a way that overwrites the existing file whenever needed, but asks the user permission before it overwrites?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Assignment8()
    Const E = 5, I = 9, L = 12  'Columns

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Base")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, L).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim newStudent As String, oldStudent As String, randNum As Long, arr As Variant
    Dim enrollPeriod As String, found As String, r As Long

    arr = ws.Range("A1:L" & lr)
    For r = 2 To lr
       If Not IsError(arr(r, L)) Then
          If Left$(arr(r, L), 6) = "262015" Then
           Randomize Format(Now, "ss")
           randNum = Int((99999 - 10000) * Rnd()) + 10000

           If IsError(arr(r, I)) Then arr(r, I) = vbNullString
           newStudent = 18 & randNum & arr(r, I)
           oldStudent = arr(r, L)
           arr(r, L) = newStudent

           If IsError(arr(r, E)) Then arr(r, E) = vbNullString
           enrollPeriod = arr(r, E)
           found = found & newStudent & ";" & oldStudent & ";" & enrollPeriod & vbNewLine
          End If
       End If
    Next
    ws.Range("A1:L" & lr) = arr
    If Len(found) > 0 Then CommitToCSV found
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CommitToCSV(ByVal newStudents As String)

    Const F_NAME = "Assignment8.csv"

    Dim confirmed As Boolean, fName As String, fileID As Long

    fName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & F_NAME

    confirmed = (Len(Dir(fName)) = 0)

    If Not confirmed Then
        confirmed = (MsgBox("Overwrite file """ & F_NAME & """?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK)
    End If

    If confirmed Then
        fileID = FreeFile
        Open fName For Output Lock Write As #fileID
        Print #fileID, Left(newStudents, Len(newStudents) - 2)
        Close #fileID
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Your code generates an empty CSV because you run it multiple times

If you run it once and it finds cells starting with `262015` in col `L`, it will update the file as expected

If you run it again and all cells starting with `262015` have been replaced by new random numbers, the file is updated with an empty string